# Do I need escape underscore when I query MySQL using JDBC preparedstatement?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I query MySQL information schema with the SQL as follow:

```sql
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES where GRANTEE=? AND TABLE_SCHEMA= ?
```

My java code fragment is:

```java
try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
     statement.setString(1, "'" + user + "'@'%'");
     statement.setString(2, schema);
     ## ignore some not related code....
}
```

My schema name is 'my_test'. I find that sometimes I need to add the underline to get the result. I can't remember the detailed info accurately. I only have some fuzzy memory that I have ever encounter the case I have to add under line escape to make the code work. And now I can't reproduce it. And sometimes I do not need escape the underline to get the result. Now can reproduced. If I add escaped will lead to empty return results. Is there any MySQL server config to decide whether we need escape the special character?

Comment: Unless it's a peculiarly of jdbc, you would never normally need to escape an underscore character. This is different from hyphen (-), which MySQL interprets as a mathematical operator, and should never be used within a table/column identifier.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably speaking about the [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) operator

If you use following predicate to match `my_test`

```
where GRANTEE like 'my_test'
```

you will match `my_test` but also `myztest` or `my2test`

because the underscore matches any single character.

To match only `my_test`  you need to escape it

```
where GRANTEE like 'my@_test' escape '@'
```

So you have to *escape* the underscore character, but *only if you use* `LIKE`- no need to escape in an equal predicate.

This is a pure database functionality, the only small relevance to JDBC has the interface
`java.sql.DatabaseMetaData` which you have to use probably only if you are in the  unlucky possition of striving for *database independece*

For example to get the list of tables in a DB independet way (for Oracle you'd query  `ALL_TABLES`) you have to

- get the interface  [DatabaseMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) and
- ask for the escape character that the drive ruses

.

```
md = con.getMetaData()
esc = md.getSearchStringEscape()
```

for my Oracle driver 12.1.0.2.0 I get the escape character as `/`

So now asking for the list of tables with the pattern `my_test`

```
md.getTables(null,null,'my_test',null)
```

I get

```
my_test
myztest
my2test
```

but using the escaped pattern   `my/_test`

```
md.getTables(null,null,'my/_test',null)
```

I get only

```
my_test
```

Comment: There is one piece of JDBC where it is potentially relevant: the `DatabaseMetaData` methods that accept a pattern (like `getTables`, `getColumns`, etc). There the proper escape should always be a backslash (\\).

Comment: @Marmite Bomber Thanks a lot. In summary, we need escape special character only when we use like in sql. JDBC will not escape our sql unless its method has explicit declaration.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for pointing to this feature. I extended the answer. Countraintuitively the escape character for Oracle driver is `'/'` the query behind uses `o.object_name LIKE :2 ESCAPE '/'`

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Ah, I had forgotten that that escape is also driver-dependent. I had it in my head that it was always `\ `, but I see it isn't (if you're curious, JDBC derives this from ODBC, as specified on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/pattern-value-arguments?view=sql-server-ver15)