# How to look for Snowflake table columns in JDBC without using a pattern for table or schema

Tags: jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The JDBC spec offers a method on the Database Metadata to detect the columns of a given table [1]. However, this method accepts patterns for the table name and the schema name.
There is the standard escape of `_` and `%` which are reserved chars for LIKE patterns.
However, Snowflake JDBC - as of 3.13.3 - is also escaping `\`. As a consequence, a table name `abc\def` is searched as plain `abcdef`, while `\` are allowed in Snowflake identifiers, according to this spec [2].

While we can manually process the string with reverse-engineering to have the correct result - like `abc\\def` - this is likely to get broken in the future.
So the question is: Is there a standard way in Snowflake to do this?

*It is possible that this behaviour is a bug in snowflake-jdbc*

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
[2] https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html#identifier-requirements

Comment: What does `getSearchStringEscape()` return?  This escape character is valid *escape* for `getTables` etc. I suspect this is not a *standard* but driver dependent.  See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64511187/4808122)

Comment: Although not very explicitly mentioned in the JDBC specification, the pattern should follow the [ODBC definition of patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/pattern-value-arguments?view=sql-server-ver15). This means that a backslash followed by a character that is not escapable, should be handled as a backslash character, and not an escape, or in other words, the driver should handle `a\b` identical to `a\\b`. If it currently isn't handled like that, it should be considered a bug in the driver (that said, having a backslash in object names is odd)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber `getSearchStringEscape()` returns `\`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I agree with you. After spending more time on Snowflake code, I think it is an issue and I opened this ticket to have a confirmation from Snowflake team https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/issues/588